# How to highlight net when selecting a net in the PCB Panel?

Tags: altium

When I am in the 2D PCB mode in Altium, I want to be able to select a net from the Net Classes, so that Altium will show that net highlighted.

How to achieve that ? (holding shift and hovering over traces is not what I want, I want to select the desired net in the PCB panel so that Altium highlights the traces)

When I select a net, Altium zooms it only in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your "Select" checkbox is not checked.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, thanks for the answer, maybe consider editing it to provide a bit more detail of where the Select box is?